# Django keep register information

Tags: python, django

I have a form to create new user.

Currently, if the user enters bad informations like weak password or a known email address, the user is redirected to the begining to the view_register. So the user has to enter his informations once again.

I just want to make sure that the register form in view_register is able to remember any previously entered informations. The user should have to possibility to edit his information to fix his email address or his password.

views :

```
def view_register(request):
    form = MinimumRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', locals())

def view_games(request):
media = settings.MEDIA
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MinimumRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        identifiant = form.cleaned_data['identifiant']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        confirm_password = form.cleaned_data['confirm_password']
        sex = form.cleaned_data['sex']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Cette adresse email est déjà utilisé.')
            return redirect(view_register)              
        if password == confirm_password:
            strengh = password[0].isalpha()
            if all(c.isalpha() == strengh for c in password):
                request.session['ident'] = '123456'
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins 8 charactères lettres et chiffres.')
                return redirect(view_register)
            else:
                form = GamesRegisterForm()
                request.session['identifiant'] = identifiant
                request.session['email'] = email
                request.session['password'] = password
                request.session['sex'] = sex
                return render(request, 'games.html', locals())
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Confirmation du mot de passe invalide.')
            return redirect(view_register)
    else:           
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Formulaire invalide.')
        return redirect(view_register)
else:
    return redirect(view_register)
```

I think that I just have to enable the variable "identifiant", "email", etc. in the "view_register". Once I have these variables, it will be easy to call them in the template.

Any idea for passing these variables to the register_view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `redirect()` your request loses POST information, so you can't populate a form object with entered data as it doesn't persist between requests.

2 ways to solve this problem.

1. Use request.session to save the information and use it to populate the form when redirecting.
2. (Recommended) Use a single view method to both display and process the registration information.

Comment: I user return render(request, 'register.html', locals()) inspite of redirect. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class based view.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class RegisterView(FormView):
    form_class = MinimumRegisterForm
    template_name = 'register.html'
    success_url = reverse(<name of your view_games view>)
```

This will do all the validation and error rendering, and if the form was valid it will redirect to the view_games view.

Answer (score 0):

In the docs there is an example of the form view.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-view

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

The line `form = NameForm(request.POST)` is important. Here the form holds all post data. When it is invalid, the form including the post data is returned to the template. Therefore the form will show up with all fields filled and error messages.

Long story short: Do not redirect when the form has errors. Return the form instance to the template.